# Python - coordinates density mean

Tags: python, geospatial, spatial, qgis

I've got few points (X,Y)

```
id,X,Y
1,11.60388710,48.10862135
2,11.60420372,48.10865659
3,11.60424066,48.10864778
4,11.60425121,48.10867597
5,11.60471031,48.10872354
6,11.60428551,48.10917455
7,11.60563380,48.10921331
8,11.60422219,48.10867773
9,11.60434356,48.10870064
10,11.60460214,48.10843284
```

[image]

and would like to find a center point (not centroid) heavily influenced by the points that are close to each other.

For example I could create a heatmap in QGIS and have something like this:

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to write a Python script to calculate this X, Y "density" center?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `scipy`'s kernel density estimation. For example (inspired by [code here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)):

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

names = ["id","X","Y"]
data = [[1,11.60388710, 48.10862135],
        [2,11.60420372, 48.10865659],
        [3,11.60424066, 48.10864778],
        [4,11.60425121, 48.10867597],
        [5,11.60471031, 48.10872354],
        [6,11.60428551, 48.10917455],
        [7,11.60563380, 48.10921331],
        [8,11.60422219, 48.10867773],
        [9,11.60434356, 48.10870064],
        [10,11.60460214, 48.10843284]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=names).set_index("id")
min_x = df["X"].min()
max_x = df["X"].max()
min_y = df["Y"].min()
max_y = df["Y"].max()

kernel = gaussian_kde(df.values.T)   # get gaussian kernel density estimate

# set up grid
grid_xs, grid_ys = np.mgrid[min_x:max_x:50j, min_y:max_y:50j]
positions = np.vstack([grid_xs.ravel(), 
                       grid_ys.ravel()])            # 2-dim array with X, Y-coordinates from xs, ys
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, grid_xs.shape)  # get densities

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.jet, extent=[min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y])
ax.set_xlim(min_x, max_x)
ax.set_ylim(min_y, max_y)
ax.scatter(df["X"], df["Y"], color="white", marker="x")
```

[image]

Of course additional [color maps](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) and formatting options are available in `matplotlib` to tweak the output to look as desired.

To get the position of the *center* (defining the center as the grid position with the highest estimated density):

```
idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(Z), Z.shape)
center = grid_xs[idx], grid_ys[idx]  # (11.604243569387755, 48.108671759387754)
```

Comment: Great, so now how to get X,Y of the center of the heatmap?

Comment: @cincin21: you could have multiple _centers_ (more or fewer depending on whether your data is multimodal and on your choice of bandwidth in the kernel density estimation). If you wanted to just get the position on the grid with highest density, you can find the largest estimated density value in `Z`.

Comment: Could you write it down in you answer? Would help a lot and others will surely benefit in the future!

Comment: @cincin21: I have added it.